# Use epsilon-delta to show a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}=3$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\displaystyle\left|\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}-3\right|<\epsilon$ for all x satisfying $0<|x|<\delta$.

So, if $|x|<\delta$, then:
$$\left|\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}-3\right| = \left|\frac{-2x^2}{x^2+1}\right| =\frac{|-2||x^2|}{\left|x^2+1\right|}=\frac{2|x^2|}{\left|x^2+1\right|}$$

This is where I'm stumped. How can I manipulate $|x|<\delta$ to look like $\left|x^2+1\right|$?

Comment: Just use $x^2+1 \geqslant 1$, whence $$\frac{2\lvert x^2\rvert}{\lvert x^2+1\rvert}\leqslant 2\lvert x^2\rvert.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you stopped, $x^2$ cannot be negative, so
$$1+x^2\ge1$$
and so
$$\frac{2|x^2|}{|1+x^2}=\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}\le2x^2\ .$$
This will be less than $\varepsilon$ if $|x|<\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$, and so this is the value you should choose for $\delta$.

**Tip**.  The really crucial thing in writing an answer to this kind of question is setting it out so that the *logic* is clear.  You should do something like this.

**Theorem**.  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}=3$.

**Proof**.  Let $\varepsilon>0$.
Choose $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$.
Suppose that $0<|x|<\delta$.  Then
. . . [your working goes here] . . .
so
$$\left|\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}-3\right|<\varepsilon\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}-3\right| = 
\frac{2|x^2|}{\left|x^2+1\right|}\le 
\frac{2\left[\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}2}\right]^2}{\left|0^2+1\right|}
= \epsilon
$$
when $|x|\leq\delta = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}2}$.